# twitter bootstrap - how to skip a line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the correct way of skipping a line? So that my image from upper row doesn't stick to the menu on the row below? (ie there should be a space between rows)

At the moment I do:

```
 <div class="row"> 
 <div class="span12"> </br></div>
 </div>
```

It seems to be acceptable since I don't break the css template in any way, but I wonder how people do it usual way.

(I am using 12 columns template)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is usually a good practise to segregate style or decoration of a page and content of a page. Decorations should be taken care of by CSS and content should be taken care of HTML.

Line break is considered as content, so it is not advisable to use line break as a style for the page.

I guess what you want is something like this.

```
.row {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This will give 20px padding at the top within `row` div.